# how to select a mesh with multiple faces quickly?

Tags: mesh

I want to selecet this shape but it has multiple faces is there anyway to easily select this shape? It part of a mesh. [image]

Comment: Select one vert then try to select all linked verteices with Ctrl + L.

Comment: I tried it but it only select small portions can I expand the area size of the selection?

Comment: It appears this mesh is comprised of many different parts, rather than one island. There probably isn't just one way to select all of it, but a combination of steps that will still be easier and quicker than just adding them one by one. I'd go to wireframe mode (Z), box (B) or circle (C) select as most of the mesh, then get the rest with Ctrl + L.

Comment: I would recreate that mesh somehow to make its topology cleaner. It will help further on not only with easier selection, but also with overall editing and rendering.

Answer (score 5):

Usually <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> selects all linked vertices. From the image you posted it looks like this should be the case in your mesh. So, if that doesn't work it could be that your mesh has some issues. What I usually do in these cases is to select everything and then hit <kbd>W</kbd>  for the Specials Menu and then choose "Remove Doubles" in order to delete double vertices, which can occur if you have accidentally split or duplicated some faces. If you are lucky that fixes your mesh so that you can try the "Select Linked Vertices" again.

Another thing you can try is "Select More": <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>NumPad +</kbd>.

Answer (score 2):

You can just hover with your mouse on the mesh and press <kbd>L</kbd>, that would select your mesh in the same way as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

Comment: `L` works not in the same way as `Ctrl`+`L`. The former selects linked vertices to those under current cursor position, while `Ctrl`+`L` selects linked to what is already selected (and cursor position doesn't matter).

Comment: Yes,, I mean that linked parts of the mesh get selected. Just as in Ctrl + L.

Answer (score 0):

Try pressing <kbd>C</kbd> to activate Circle select tool and then expand your radius to select a lot of it.

Comment: This would miss any occluded vertices, though.